# How to upgrade RStudio version?

Tags: r

Recently I've tried to install `keras` package in R. I ran the following commands:
`install.packages("keras") library(keras)`

But when I ran `is_keras_avalable()` I got FALSE.

I was told, that the problem with unsuccessful 'keras' installation may come from the old RStudio version, which is installed on my notebook (I work in RStudio 3.4.0). I was adviced to reinstall RStudio and to get a brand new version.

Could you, please, tell me how to do it? I'd be very pleased if you provide me with the necessary links for installing the latest RStudio version on Windows 8.1.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can download R Studio from [here](https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download) and learn how to install `keras` in R from [here](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/guide/keras/) and [here](https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/install_keras.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RStudio is an application (specifically, an Integrated Development Environment, or IDE). This is a common tool for using R, which is a computer language. Much like Microsoft Word is a common tool for writing documents in English (or other languages - and in fact you can use RStudio to write files other languages like RMarkdown, Python, SQL, French, or Swahili.). However, just like you can write English in programs other than Word, you can also write and run R code in programs other than RStudio.

You can find the most recent version [on the RStudio website](https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/), or you can look in the `Help` menu and select "Check for updates", which will give you a download link if a newer version is available.

[image]

Given the version number you show, 3.4.0, you need to upgrade R (the language), not RStudio (the application). The current RStudio version as I write this is 1.3.*, while the current R version is 4.0.*.

The place you need to go to update R is CRAN - [their website](https://cran.r-project.org/) has download links for Windows, Mac, and Linux.

Comment: This is all true. However I'm guessing they are needing to update R itself. One shouldn't need a specific version of rstudio for general R packages to work. That on top of them saying "RStudio 3.4.0" makes me think they are just running an old version of R.

Comment: Lol - didn't notice the version number. Thanks, I'll edit.

Comment: New users very often confuse RStudio with R.  I'd say a majority of the questions on reddit.com/r/rstudio are just questions about R itself.